# Where to Host a .cur image

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

.cur is an image extension for mouse Cursors

I have purchased a custom domain via Blogger.Unlike Wordpress,blogger does not have any directory of webfiles or something where things can be uploaded

I need to change the default cursor of my mouse in my website.Unfortunately,Google's Picassa or Imageshack/phobucket do not support .cur files.

I found some other image sites while googling,but all are old  image hosting services which no longer exist.

I tried dropbox,google code,but they provide a link to download the .cur image and not actually give a url which i can link in my css.

Is there any way to host .cur Images.Please Help.Thanks.

Comment: oh!i remember using this technique earlier,but in vain.Today i re-applied and its working great!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Thanks a ton...plz can u convert ur comment into an answer so that i can offer bounty :)

Comment: Done! Good to see this alternative worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to keep this file in the `cur` format? Isn't converting it to, say, PNG an option?

I'm not even sure every browser/OS out there supports `cur` (though I've seen [examples online](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/create-custom-cursors-with-javascript-and-css3.html) with this format, so I might be mistaken). Converting to a more standard format might ensure better portability, besides saving you the hassle of looking for a host with such specific requirements.